# Black screen. After compaq splash logo BIOS error?

Tags: windows, bios

I got here a Compaq cq50. That shows black immediately after the compaq splash screen. Is this some kind if motherboard problem ?? Cause I've tried unsuccessfully to flash the bios.

Comment: Does the system turn off? Can you get into the BIOS itself by pressing the correct keys while the splash screen is showing?

Comment: Has it worked before? Has anything been changed lately, either in hardware or software? Has the machine been moved to a new location?

Comment: It was a bios problem. I already took it down for repair. Since I was unable to flash  the bios myself

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to boot into BIOS by pressing F10? If that works, the problem is most likely somewhere else.

It might be an OS problem, try removing HDD and see if the laptop boots the same way. If it does, then it might be an BIOS-problem. You can also try to boot using an live-cd, just to make sure that the problem is not related to the OS.

Comment: It freezes when f10 is pressed.

Comment: Okay, so it's most definitely an BIOS problem. There is still some hope. As far as I can tell, this is similar problem: http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-compaq-presario-g-series-mini-notebooks/713441-cq50-won-t-boot.html So adding the BIOS files to usb-stick and booting with Win+B should initiate the BIOS reflashing

Comment: Thanks zokol for the prompt reply. Will try the solution. And post result.